# LookAt Matrix (Normalising Parallel Projection)

Tags: javascript, matrix, graphics, 3d

I am currently learning 3d computer graphics and normalising parallel projection into canocial view volume(LookAt Matrix as the familiar name). I try to implement it to the code using pure javascript as the parameter below.

```
var VRP = new Vertex(0,0,0);
var VPN = new Vertex(0,0,1);
var VUP = new Vertex(0,1,0);
var PRP = new Vertex(8,8,100);
var Window = [-1,17,-1,17];
var F = 1, B = -1;
```

Now, here is my attempt. I converted it first to canocial view volume.
**NOTE: You can skip these steps directly to the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Marfin/hL2bmvz5/20/) and help me to fix the code to move the cube forward to camera(the screen) instead of moving away**

**1. Translate VRP to origin**

```
var TVRP = [];
TVRP[0] = [1, 0, 0, -VRP.x];
TVRP[1] = [0, 1, 0, -VRP.y];
TVRP[2] = [0, 0, 1, -VRP.z];
TVRP[3] = [0, 0, 0, 1];
```

**2. Rotate VRC such that n-axis,u-axis and v-axis align with z-axis, x-axis, and y-axis in order**

```
function normalizeViewPlane(VPN) {
    var unitVector = calculateUnitVector(VPN); //VPN/|VPN|
    return normalizeVector(VPN,unitVector);
}

function normalizeViewUp(VUP, n) {
    var dtProd = dotProduct(n,VUP);
    var nVUP = new Vertex(n.x*dtProd, n.y*dtProd, n.z*dtProd);
    VUP = new Vertex(VUP.x-nVUP.x, VUP.y-nVUP.y, VUP.z-nVUP.z);
    var unitVector = calculateUnitVector(VUP); //VUP/|VUP|
    return normalizeVector(VUP,unitVector);
}

function normalizeUVN(n,u) {
    var V = crossProduct(n,u);
    var unitVector = calculateUnitVector(V); //V/|V|
    return normalizeVector(V,unitVector);
}

var n = normalizeViewPlane(VPN);
var v = normalizeViewUp(VUP, n);
var u = normalizeUVN(v, n);

var RVRC = [];
RVRC[0] = [u.x, u.y, u.z, 0];
RVRC[1] = [v.x, v.y, v.z, 0];
RVRC[2] = [n.x, n.y, n.z, 0];
RVRC[3] = [0, 0, 0, 1];
//Perform matrix multiplication 4x4 R.T(-VRP)
var res = multiplyMatrix4x4(RVRC, TVRP);
```

**3. Shear DOP becomes parallel to z-axis**

```
function shearDOP(PRP, uMaxMin, vMaxMin) {
    var CW = new Vertex(uMaxMin,vMaxMin,0);
    var mPRP = new Vertex(PRP.x,PRP.y,PRP.z);
    return new Vertex(CW.x - mPRP.x, CW.y - mPRP.y, CW.z - mPRP.z);
}

var uMaxMin = (Window[1]+Window[0])/2;
var vMaxMin = (Window[3]+Window[2])/2;
var DOP = shearDOP(PRP,uMaxMin,vMaxMin);       
var HX = (DOP.x/DOP.z)*-1;
var HY = (DOP.y/DOP.z)*-1;

 var Hpar = [];
 Hpar[0] = [1,0,HX,0];
 Hpar[1] = [0,1,HY,0];
 Hpar[2] = [0,0,1,0];
 Hpar[3] = [0,0,0,1];
 //res = R.T(-VRP)
 res = multiplyMatrix4x4(Hpar,res);
```

**4. Translate to front center of the view volume origin**

```
var Tpar = [];
Tpar[0] = [1,0,0,-uMaxMin];
Tpar[1] = [0,1,0,-vMaxMin];
Tpar[2] = [0,0,1,-F];
Tpar[3] = [0,0,0,1];
//res=Hpar.R.T(-VRP)
res = multiplyMatrix4x4(Tpar,res);
```

**5. Scale such that view volume becomes bounded by plane**

```
var uMaxMin2 = 2/(Window[1]-Window[0]);
var vMaxMin2 = 2/(Window[3]-Window[2]);
var Spar = [];
Spar[0] = [uMaxMin2, 0, 0, 0];
Spar[1] = [0, vMaxMin2, 0, 0];
Spar[2] = [0, 0, 1 / (F - B), 0];
Spar[3] = [0, 0, 0, 1];
 //res=Tpar.Hpar.R.T(-VRP)
res = multiplyMatrix4x4(Spar, res);
```

After convert it to the canocial view volume, I decided to multiply cube vertices to this final result transformation matrix.

```
//res=Spar.Tpar.Hpar.R.T(-VRP)
p = multiplyMatrix1x4(res,p);
//M is the parameter of cube vertice
M.x = p[0];
M.y = p[1];
M.z = p[2];
```

Thus, I had my cube is moving away from the camera as it is illustrated in image below.

[image: the cube moving away]

However, I expect that cube is move closest to the camera instead of moving away as it is explained in image below(the object is house)

[image: The house move closest to the camera]

Am I missing the step or misunderstanding the algorithm of converting to canocial view volume? Which function or variable I shall modify to make the cube like the house above?
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Marfin/hL2bmvz5/20/
Reference: https://telin.ugent.be/~sanja/ComputerGraphics/L06_Viewing_Part2_6pp.pdf

Comment: if your only issue is the z-direction of the movement, you probably messed up the coord-system somewhere. lets dump the coords of the cam and the box before and after the movement...!

Comment: @draz Ok I am new in computer graphics and 3d projection, I changed parameter above(vrp,vpn,vup) but the cube position in z-direction still the same. Unless I changed the size of the cube but it does not apply how the 3d camera projecting the object

Comment: if the z-position of the box is the same, you are moving the cam backwards obviously. the z-axis points towards the cam, so if you increase cam.z, the cam is moving away.

Comment: in general, if your cam is looking at the box and you want the cam to move towards the box, get the vector between cam and box and move the cam towards this direction: `cam += (box-cam)`

Comment: @draz Wow !! `cam+=(box-cam)` is work! So you are pointing my mistake in the last step. Instead of multiplying each box I have to get the vector between cam and box. Thank you so much!! But you can provide the answer and explanation and I will tick as accepted answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general, if your cam is looking at the box and you want the cam to move towards the box, get the vector between cam and box and move the cam towards this direction:

`cam += (box-cam)`